# Rails No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"session"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

I'm working on a Rails App that has authentication, and am getting an error that reads:

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"session"}, missing required keys: [:id]

I'm getting this error when trying to render the "new" view from the sessions controller, and can't figure out why it's referencing the destroy method when it should just be looking at the New/Create methods.  Below is how I have my routes, my controller, my model, and my view set up, if anybody could give me some guidance as to what I need to check it'd be greatly appreciated.

Routes:

`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "root#index"
    resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :index, :show]
    resources :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :pets
end`

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  PASSWORD_LENGTH = (6..25)
  USERNAME_LENGTH = (5..25)

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates :username, length: USERNAME_LENGTH, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, length: PASSWORD_LENGTH, allow_nil: true

  has_many :pets

  attr_reader :password

  def self.find_from_credentials(username, password)
    user = find_by(username: username)
    return nil unless user
    user if user.is_password?(password)
  end

  def is_password?(password_attempt)
    BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest).is_password?(password_attempt)
  end

  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController

    before_action :ensure_signed_out, only: [:new, :create]

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        username = user_params[:username]
        password = user_params[:password]

        user = User.find_from_credentials(username, password)

        if user
            sign_in(user)
            flash[:notice] = "#{username} has successfully signed in."
            redirect_to "/"
        else
            flash[:error] = "User not found."
            @user = User.new(username: username)
            render :new
        end
    end

    def destroy
        sign_out
        flash[:notice] = "User signed out."
        redirect_to new_session_path
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
    end
end
```

View:

```
<h2>Enter your credentials below: </h2>

<%= form_for :user, url: session_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :username, placeholder: 'Username', required: true %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', required: true %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Log in' %>
<% end %>


<p> Don't have an account?  <%= link_to 'Sign up here!', new_user_path %></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow — great first question!

Starting from the top: When you call `resources` inside your `routes.rb` file, you're telling Rails to make routes for standard CRUD.

Now, according to people smarter than you and me — aka the guys that pour their blood/sweat/tears into Rails — and by RESTful standards, to delete a resource — in your case, a `Session` — requires the server to respond to a DELETE-type request (GET/POST/PATCH/PUT/DELETE... there are more) in the matter of,

`DELETE /sessions/1`

Rails maps this like so:

`match '/sessions/:id' => 'sessions#destroy', :via => :delete`

the `via` is important. Note, `match` could also just be `delete` and we could omit the `via`.

Now because I don't have your entire view file, it's hard to pinpoint where this is happening. But know that if you have an intention of deleting a Session resource, you need to know its ID, which is what this error is trying to tell you: generating the URL helper (some Rails magic) for that path requires a persisted Session.

Comment: I'm messing up my replies, sorry if this is spamming your inbox.

The View file I posted is the entire view file, if there's a different file you'd need let me know and I'll gladly post it.

I get what you're saying about what the error is saying, that's clearer.  What I'm struggling with is why the New view would be referencing the Destroy method as soon as it loads.  My understanding was that the Views only reference their specific method in the controller.

Comment: Then you'll want to use the `sessions_index_path` it looks like. That routes to the create action in the sessions controller, right?

Comment: Oh that's a way easier fix!  The other comment had me thinking it was something in my routes, but making the change in the View fixed the issue perfectly, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Side note first: If you're using Rails 5.x then you'll want to use a `form_with` in your view. 
[Check it out here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#unification-of-form-for-and-form-tag-into-form-with)

I believe the problem is with the url you're using for your form. You're telling the form to submit a `post` request to the url that would lead to the `session#show` action (`session_path`), but that doesn't exist and you're not sending in an instance of a session which is why it says it's missing the id.

Your form should probably look like this (you may have just been missing an 's':

```
<h2>Enter your credentials below: </h2>
# you will need to run 'rails routes' in your terminal to find out the exact prefix, but you want the prefix that routes to 'sessions#create'
<%= form_with url: sessions_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :username, placeholder: 'Username', required: true %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', required: true %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Log in' %>
<% end %>


<p> Don't have an account?  <%= link_to 'Sign up here!', new_user_path %></p>
```

Comment: I took another look at my routes, focusing on the session routes:
session_index POST   /session(.:format)       session#create  <br/>
  new_session GET    /session/new(.:format)   session#new  <br/>
      session DELETE /session/:id(.:format)   session#destroy  <br/>
I think my first issue is changing the DELETE URI Pattern to /session, and my second issue is that POST is missing from that session route as well.  I'll keep tinkering and see if I can get those changes to fix.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Then it looks like the url helper you should be using is `session_index_path` because that goes to the create action in the sessions controller, right?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with URL that was being used in the form, as it should've been pointing to session_index_path based on my routes.  Thanks to all that responded!